# Amazon RDS Postgresql snapshot preserves schema but loses all data

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, relational-database, missing-data, snapshot

Using AWS RDS console I created a snapshot backup of a Postgresql v11 database containing multiple schemas. I then created a new instance from the backup. The process seemed to work fine without error. However, upon inspection of the data in the new instance, I noticed that in only one of my schemas the data was not preserved. The schema structure, tables, indexes, constraints, etc looked fine, but every table was empty (select count(*) from schema.table was 0 for every table in the schema). All other schemas looked fine and contained the expected data. I looked everywhere (could not find help for this online) and tried many tests myself (changing roles, rebuilding the schema, privileges, much more) while attempting to solve this issue. What would cause my snapshots to preserve the entire schema structure, but lose all of the data itself?

Comment: If you turn that into a question with a (self-written) answer, I'll upvote.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange, you have asked a good question and even found the answer. Ettiquite here requires that answer are put into the answer section so that you can receive the apropriate rewards. and to help others to see that this question has an answer.  just cut and paste your last paragraph into the box at the bottom and click `Post Your Answer`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have rephrased my initial post as a question and included a self-written answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally realized that the only difference between the problem schema and the other was that all tables in the problem schema had been created with the 'UNLOGGED' keyword. This was done to increase write speed for millions of rows inserted when the schema was first built. However, when a snapshot is created/restored as described above, the process depends on the WAL files that are written with normal (logged) tables to restore the data. To fix my problem I simply altered all of the tables and set them to be logged (alter table schema.table set logged). After this, snapshots worked fine. For anyone else in the future that is doing something similar, should unlogged tables be needed for initial mass population of data to get better write speed, it would be a good to changed them to be logged after initial data population (if you plan on using snapshots or replications or similar). Side note, pg_dump/pg_restore does still work for unlogged tables.